# How to disable adding of elements in CRUD?

Tags: php, user-interface, crud, atk4

How to prevent user from being able to add new entries in a standard CRUD View in Agile Toolkit?

```
$this->add('CRUD')->setModel('User');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRUD has a property `$allow_add` which would disable add functionality. You should use this code to set the initial value of object property in Agile Toolkit:

```
$this->add('CRUD',array('allow_add'=>false))->setModel('User');
```

Alternatively you can use Grid, if you don't wish to have editing or you want to customize editing page:

```
$this->add('Grid')->setModel('User');
```

Comment: Is that also in 4.1 or only a new feature of 4.2 ?

Comment: Do you mean the ability to set the properties through second argument? I think it's 4.2 only: https://github.com/atk4/atk4/commit/3c1f42b46ef24ffa44cba401b36cea80b68fdf4e